# jqTouch/JavaScript alerts - how to remove the title?

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications, notifications

Looking to have some alerts/prompts pop up in my iPhone web app but I see the Title is at the top of the alert (I understand this is the normal behavior). My question is can I remove this? or use an alternative solution.

Looking for something that looks like the push notification alert but in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change the default behavior of those popups. What you could do is make a screen filling div which looks the same as the push notification message and handle it's appearance and disappearance in jQuery. With the supported HTML5 and CSS3 options it's a piece of cake :)

But isn't it more stylish to slide in your own layout from the bottom, or use the flip animation?

Comment: hmm didn't think of that. Thnk